# How to add legend within a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am trying to scatter some datapoints in `matplotlib` but am having some issues with displaying the legend properly.
After importing and initializing

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

x = rng.uniform(0, 3, 5)
y = rng.uniform(0, 5, 5)
labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
colors = [plt.cm.plasma(i / float(len(labels))) for i in range(len(labels))]
```

I run a (less than I thought) simple`plt.scatter`

```
# scatter strategy 1
scatter1 = plt.figure()
scatter1 = plt.scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    c=colors,
    cmap=cm.plasma,
    label=labels,
)
handles, labels = scatter1.legend_elements(num=list(np.unique(labels)))
plt.legend(handles, labels, loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

just to discover that handles and labels are empty lists. This results in the legend not being displayed.
How can I fix this, and why?

On a sidenote, I also tried plotting each datapoint one by one with a for loop, as follows:

```
# scatter strategy 2
scatter2 = plt.figure()
unique = np.unique(labels)

for i, u, color in zip(range(len(unique)), unique, colors):
    xi = x[i]
    yi = y[i]
    plt.scatter(xi, yi, color=color, cmap=cm.plasma, label=str(unique))
plt.show()
```

to no good, as it seems like the figure is not being "filled" with the data. Why is it so, and how could I fix it? How to properly compile a legend in this latter example?

Comment: You want each point with the possibility of a unique color / label? So you got x, y, colors and labels properly defined?

Comment: Yes! Each point has its own unique label in the actual dataset. Labels are strings formatted in LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are looking for the answer with a for loop, the second (strategy 2) is the one I modified. See if this is what you are looking for...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

x = rng.uniform(0, 3, 5)
y = rng.uniform(0, 5, 5)
labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
colors = [plt.cm.plasma(i / float(len(labels))) for i in range(len(labels))]

# scatter strategy 2
scatter2 = plt.figure()
unique = np.unique(labels)

for i in range(len(unique)): ##Simplified a bit
    plt.scatter(x[i], y[i], color=colors[i], cmap=cm.plasma, label=labels[i])  ## Updates here... should be colors[i] and labels[i]

plt.legend()  ## You will need this
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to calculate the colors yourself, let matplotlib do it and just use your labels as is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(0)

x = rng.uniform(0, 3, 5)
y = rng.uniform(0, 5, 5)
labels = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

scatter1 = plt.scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    c=range(len(labels)),
    cmap="plasma",
    vmax=len(labels)
)
handles, _ = scatter1.legend_elements()
plt.legend(handles, labels, loc="lower right")
```

[image]

Comment: this solution seems neat, but I get `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'legend_elements'`. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Do you get the error when you just copy and paste this very example? Please verify that you call `legend_elements` on the return value of `plt.scatter` without any re-assignments to this value in-between.